# Cast timestamp column to Python datetime format in KDB

Tags: python, datetime, kdb

I have a table `tbl` with column `datetime` in KDB's `timestamp` format which looks like `2014.11.22D17:43:40.123456789`. I would like to cast this into a Python datetime format like this `2014-11-22 17:43:40.123456789` but I am having trouble using the `update` command.

I understand that I can do this to cast the timestamp:

```
q)`year`dd`mm`hh`uu`ss$2015.10.28D03:55:58 // this gives 2015 28 10 3 55 58i
```

And I understand I can create a new column `datetime2` from `datetime` by reading it as a string then converting it into integer in this case:

```
q)update datetime2:"I"$string datetime from tbl
```

But I am having difficulty casting and updating at the same time:

```
q)update datetime2:`year-`dd-`mm `hh:`uu:`ss$datetime from tbl
```

The error I got is:

```
evaluation error:

length

  [0]  update datetime2:`year-`dd-`mm `hh:`uu:`ss$datetime from tbl
                                                 ^
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kdb doesn't have an alternative method of displaying timestamps, the only way to get what you're looking for is to string the timestamps and manipulate the individual characters. Something like:

```
q)tbl:([]datetime:5#2014.11.22D17:43:40.123456789)
q)update{" "sv'(ssr[;".";"-"];::)@'/:"D"vs'string x}datetime from tbl
datetime
-------------------------------
"2014-11-22 17:43:40.123456789"
"2014-11-22 17:43:40.123456789"
"2014-11-22 17:43:40.123456789"
"2014-11-22 17:43:40.123456789"
"2014-11-22 17:43:40.123456789"
```

This is purely cosmetic and these timestamps would be unusable in a timeseries sense, however maybe they suit your purpose.

What problem are you ultimately trying to solve? If you're trying to pass the data to python you might be better off working with the underlying numerical values and converting the numerical value back to timestamp on the python side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `qdate` library from https://code.kx.com/analyst/libraries/date-parser/

```
q).qdate.print["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N"; 2014.11.22D17:43:40.123456789]
"2014-11-22 17:43:40.123456789"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're planning to read the data into a python file, then it would be best to cast the dates to a long in your update statement, which represent the number of nanoseconds after epoch:

```
update datetime2:`long$datetime from tbl
```

and then convert the longs back into python datetimes in your python file, otherwise you could convert it to a string in the table then alter the individual characters to put it in python datetime form (this would only make sense if the data is staying inside kdb)

another way to go could be to use the PyQ or embedpy libraries, these load python and q interpreters into the same process and support type conversion:

https://pythonhosted.org/pyq/

https://github.com/KxSystems/embedPy